# Limiting the number of the Many in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am attempting to limit the number of the 'many' in a one-to-many using Flask-SQLAlchemy. I want to allow only 3 or less 'mouse' (mice) per 'blind' row.

Here is my basic setup...

```
class Blind(db.Model):
    __tablename__   = 'blind'
    #this __table_args__ does not work
    #__table_args__  = ((db.CheckConstraint('length(blind_mice <= 3)')),)
    id              = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # I want to limit the blind_mice
    #relationship to a count of 3 mice per 'Blind' id
    blind_mice      = db.relationship('Mouse')


class Mouse(db.Model):
    __tablename__   = 'mouse'
    id              = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    blind_id    = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('blind.id'))
    blind       = db.relationship("Blind")
```

I tried using a CheckConstraint from sqlalchemy (see the commented out __table_args__ above), but that causes the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such column: blind_mice u'\nCREATE 
TABLE blind (\n\tid INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id), \n\tCHECK (length(blind_mice 
<= 3))\n)\n\n' ()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After messing with this problem for a few hours I started looking at sqlalchemy event documentation. This is best I could come up with.

```
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

MAX_MICE_PER_BLIND = 3


class Blind(db.Model):
    __tablename__       = 'blind'
    id                  = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    blind_mice          = db.relationship('Mouse')


class Mouse(db.Model):
    __tablename__   = 'mouse'
    id              = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    blind_id        = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('blind.id'))
    blind           = db.relationship("Blind")


@event.listens_for(Mouse.blind_id, 'set', retval=True)
def mice_per_blind_check(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    if value is not None:
        mice_count = Mouse.query.filter_by(blind_id=value).count()
        if mice_count >= MAX_MICE_PER_BLIND:
            orig = Exception('Maximum number of Mice ({}) '\
                             'reached for Blind.id = {}'\
                             .format(MAX_MICE_PER_BLIND, value))
            msg = "Record Not Committed"
            raise IntegrityError(msg, ';)', orig)
    return value
```

This solution throws an IntegrityError which when used with Flask-Restless causes a HTTP 400 Bad Request, but does not interrupt Flask server operation. Additionally, this solution does not allow a 4th mouse with blind_id = n to exist. Great Success!

Comment: I know this is very old. Have you come across another, less manual approach? As you originally intended, I would also like to use the Constraint API. Also, a link to the documentation you mentioned would be helpful :)

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.AttributeEvents.set